Use wagtail form into other templates
So I have created a Form with the Wagtail Form Builder and works well.
Now I want to use the created from into other templates throughout my project.
I have originally created the form for the Contact Page, but now I want this same form to be use in other templates such as lets say a Blog Page, under the post as a contact form.
Is there any way to do that? Thanks a lot!
I dont know where to start because i cant really bring the ID or value of the specific form.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
